# Influence of word counts from DTM on LDA with Gibbs Sampling

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining, gibbs, topic-models, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I'm trying to wrap my head around Topic Modeling based on LDA with Gibbs sampling *(Griffiths, Steyvers 2004: Finding Scientific Topics)*. What struck me when reading some Python implementations like [this one](https://gist.github.com/mblondel/542786) or [that one](https://github.com/hannawallach/python-lda/blob/master/src/lda.py), was that it *appears* that the actual word counts in the input matrix (the document-term-matrix – DTM) are never used in the calculations. When iterating over the words in a document, it is done so by iterating over the non-zero occurrences of words in the vocabulary (`for w in word_indices(matrix[m, :]): ...` – *m* denotes a document index) but the actual word count is not used in the calculations for the probability distribution `p_z` (prob. across topics given a word in a document).

So it appears to me, that for the algorithm it is only important *if* a word exists in a document and not *how often* it occurs there. If this was the case, then with a binary DTM that only denotes if a certain word occurs in a document or not, we would achieve similar results as with a conventional DTM containing the number of word occurrences. However, this is not (or should not be) the case and this confuses me. Can someone clarify this? Did I miss something or are the referenced implementations wrong? How and where do the actual word counts in a DTM influence the results?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I found my error in reasoning. I thought that the LDA algorithm operates on the document-term-matrix (DTM) containing the raw word counts. However, in the [implementation](https://github.com/lda-project/lda/blob/develop/lda/utils.py#L29) of the [lda python package](http://pythonhosted.org/lda/), I found that the DTM is "expanded" to a binary matrix where the occurrences of words per document are repeated (technically, it's only an array with the repeated indices of the words).

So this DTM with two documents *d1* and *d2* and a vocabulary consisting only of "foo" and "bar":

```
   | foo | bar
--------------
d1 |   3 |   2
d2 |   1 |   0
```

Becomes:

```
   | foo | foo | foo | bar | bar
--------------------------------
d1 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   1 |   1
d2 |   1 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0
```

So LDA treats each occurrence of a word independently, while I initially thought that it uses a weight like the count 3 for a word "foo" and then calculates the prob. distribution based on that weight.

That's the case for LDA using Gibbs sampling at least. Regarding the other approaches, I have no idea.